# Eliminating overlapping entries based on start / end values in bash

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, awk, overlap

I have a tab-delimited file of entries that have a start and end position

```
# Name \t Start \t End
Name1 \t 1 \t 3
Name2 \t 7 \t 9
Name3 \t 5 \t 8
Name4 \t 5 \t 6
```

I want to delete lines that overlap with earlier lines. In this example, the desired output would be

```
Name1 \t 1 \t 3
Name2 \t 7 \t 9
Name4 \t 5 \t 6
```

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\n' read line; do
     # Assign variable names
     name=$(echo $line | cut -f 1)
     start=$(echo $line | cut -f 2)
     end=$(echo $line | cut -f 3)
     # I envision an if statement structured so that:
     # if [ $end < $PreviousStart ] || [ $start > $PreviousEnd ] ; then echo $line >> output.txt
done < file.txt
```

This is where I get stuck because I would need to check each line of output.txt (all the previous lines from my original file) and only print $line if the if statement is satisfied for all current lines of output.txt.
I was thinking awk may have a solution for this that is less circuitous...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: fwiw, if you *need* a solution in `bash` it should be fairly easy to convert either of the `awk` answers/scripts into comparable `bash` scripts

Answer (score 3):

You can keep previous non-overlapping start and end positions as indices and values in an array in awk so you can easily iterate through them for each record to test if the current start and end positions overlap with any of them, and skip the current record if they do:

```
awk '-F\t' '{for(s in a)if($2<=a[s]&&s<=$3)next;a[$2]=$3}1' file.txt
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=REkxdr

Comment: That would fail if you added 1 more input row containing `Name5 7 8` since `7 8` is inside the range specific by `Name3 5 8` but `a[$2]=$3` would discard the range `5 8` when you read `Name4 5 6` after it. You'd need `a[$2]=$3` to be `a[$2]=($2 in a && a[$2] > $3 : a[$2] : $3)` or similar.

Comment: No. `Name3 5 8` is completely discarded not because `Name4 5 6` overwrites it, but because it overlaps with `Name2 7 9`. It is clear from the OP's expected output that when a range overlaps with an earlier range, it is completely discarded. If you keep `Name3 5 8` in the array it would make `Name4 5 6` overlap with it and prevent `Name4 5 6` from being in the output, which clearly isn't what the OP wants. Using a simple array works because any duplicating start position is supposed to be completely discarded in the first place.

Comment: I misread your script - some white space would vastly improve it's clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- as we read a new line we need to test for overlaps against *all* previous non-overlapping lines
- if a new line does not overlap with any of the previous non-overlapping lines then ...
- *a)* we save the new line as a new member of the group of non-overlapping lines and
- *b)* print the new line to stdout

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
      { for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++)                            # loop through array of previous lines
            if ( ( $2 >= start[i] && $2 <= end[i] ) ||    # does current "start" overlap with a previous line?
                 ( $3 >= start[i] && $3 <= end[i] )    )  # does current "end" overlap with a previous line?
                 next                                     # if there is an overlap then skip this line and process the next line of input 

        start[++cnt] = $2                                 # we have a new non-overlapping line so save the start and end points
        end[cnt] = $3
        print                                             # print current line to stdout
      }
' file.txt
```

This generates:

```
Name1   1       3
Name2   7       9
Name4   5       6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare name
declare -a startArr endArr
declare -i start end overlapping

while IFS=$'\t' read -r name start end; do
   if ((${#name}==0)); then continue; fi
   overlapping=0
   for ((i=0; i<${#startArr[*]}; i++))
      {
      if (( start >= ${startArr[i]} && start <= ${endArr[i]} || end >= ${startArr[i]} && end <= ${endArr[i]} || start < ${startArr[i]} && end > ${endArr[i]} )); then 
         overlapping=1;
         break;
      fi
      }
   if ((overlapping)); then continue; fi
   echo "$name"$'\t'"$start"$'\t'"$end"
   startArr+=($start); endArr+=($end)
 done < file1
```

file1:

```
Name1   1   3
Name2   7   9
Name3   5   8
Name4   5   6
Name5   4   10   # edited this line , other case of overlapping
```